# Signing Stopped , with 6 signers nodes

Tags: tomochain

I ran a private tomochain network with 6 signers , due to a server issue , i had to restart all nodes , but after restart the nodes are unable to sign

Following are the related logs -

```
Signed recently, must wait for others
len(masternodes)=6 number=703437 limit=2 seen=703436
recent=0xBa4C4Ea03b46A24fE08507B2b47Abbe92E8d10db
snap.Recents="map[703433:[237 251 115 119 211 59 13 15 38 86 117 108 174 145 242 148 60 88 234 166] 703434:[115 253 194 39 153 65 170 201 233 144 90 159 172 191 233 27 53 61 6 62] 703435:[141 170 200 132 116 212 101 168 112 116 253 32 83 16 66 222 34 95 9 71] 703436:[186 76 78 160 59 70 162 79 224 133 7 178 180 122 187 233 46 141 16 219]]"
```

On the other signers the logs are like

```
Committing new block , number=703437 txs=0 special-txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=337.344µs,
Successfully sealed new block number=703437 hash=fd51a0…6aafb9
```

I have also faced similar issues with 4 signers , 3 signers etc. What could be done here ?

Comment: What tomochain version do you use?

Comment: my tomochain version is 1.5.3

Comment: You should use the latest v1.5.7

Comment: Ok i will try , can you point me to the commit or commit list which fixes this ? And why this happens ?

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue on our side